# How to add image in top left or start and ending of the text in textview android?

Tags: android, textview

I have start & end double quotes as image and have to place it in the start and end of the text in the textview just like in the image.  How it can be done?

[image]

Comment: You should use Spannable. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842535/show-emoticon-using-spannable-on-a-text-view

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
txtview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                R.drawable.image, 0, 0, 0);
```

Or in your xml file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/name"/>
```

**android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"**

You can replace Left for other gravity.